# How to covert dataframe with variable column size per row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
ID      Code
5966856 A
5966856 B
5966857 A
5966854 A
5966854 B
5966854 C
6648070 A
6648074 A
6648075 B
```

I wish to convert it to:

```
ID      Code_1 Code_2 Code_3
5966856 A      B      NaN
5966857 A      NaN    NaN
5966854 A      B      C
6648070 A      NaN    NaN
6648074 A      NaN    NaN
6648075 B      NaN    NaN
```

I tried groupby and pivot but in either case I need to define columns and in my case those columns are variable.
The max number of columns is equal to the max Codes per unique ID. For the rest I populate as NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

- first convert column `Code` to `list`s per group
- then use `DataFrame` contructor
- `rename` columns by custom function
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`

---

```
a = df.groupby('ID')['Code'].apply(list)
c = lambda x: 'Code_{}'.format(x+1)
df = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist(), index=a.index).rename(columns=c).reset_index()
```

Alternative:

- create Series by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for `Counter`, add `1`, cast to `string` and add from right by [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html)
- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column and `Series`
- reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
- [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for column from `index`

---

```
a = df.groupby('ID')['Code'].cumcount().add(1).astype(str).radd('Code_')
df = df.set_index(['ID', a])['Code'].unstack().reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
        ID Code_1 Code_2 Code_3
0  5966854      A      B      C
1  5966856      A      B   None
2  5966857      A   None   None
3  6648070      A   None   None
4  6648074      A   None   None
5  6648075      B   None   None
```